# Avoid double function calling on overlaying images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

I have one smaller image laying on top of a bigger one, and both are connected on click to a jQuery function.

My problem is when I click the smaller one, the browser first executes the function connected to the smaller one, and then it also executes the function connected to the bigger one.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer" style="position: relative; width:200px; height:200px; background:#00f;">
    <div id="inner" style="position: absolute; top:100px; left:100px; width:50px; height:50px; background:#0f0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#outer').click(function(){
    alert('outer');
})

$('#inner').click(function(){
    alert('inner');
})
```

Or see jFiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/XmG2T/**.

How do I prevent the browser, when I click the smaller image, from also executing the second function connected to the bigger image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the event bubbling from the child element to it's parent.

> `event.stopPropagation()` - Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
>   tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('#inner').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('inner');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XmG2T/1/)**

```
$('#inner').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('inner');
});
```